# AllowedOrigin: * doesn't work with S3 multiple domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For my s3 bucket, I had a CORs configuration file with a wildcard origin rule `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>`

I received this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header 
when the credentials flag is true. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

so I changed the rule to `<AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:8100</AllowedOrigin>`

However after changing my CORs configuration file; I still get the above error, and my response header from s3 still shows the wildcard setting -  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Is this CORs file cached somewhere? If it is, how do I refresh/reset it, I have tried deleting the CORs configuration from the bucket, and creating a new one, but that doesn't solve the problem.
My CORs config file (before and after editing) is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

I changed this to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:8100</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:8100</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is likely to be related to the fact that you are testing with "localhost," which is a magic value in some cases. Try using `http://lvh.me:8100/` instead, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @michael-sqlbot I've just tried this, I still receive the header - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in my response, so it doesn't fix it. The file seems to be cached somewhere, because even when I delete the file - I still get the same response.